# Why do we set $x+1=\frac{1}{t}$ When we compute $I= \int_{{1}/{2}}^{0} \frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{(3-x)(x+1)}}.$

Tags: definite-integrals

When we compute $I=\displaystyle \int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^{0} \dfrac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{(3-x)(x+1)}}.$
 We set $x+1=\dfrac{1}{t}$ and we have $\displaystyle I=\int\limits_1^2\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{4t-1}}$.

I have a question : "Why do we set $x+1=\dfrac{1}{t}$?"

Riemann integral.

Comment: You don't have to. There are many other transformations that also work.

Comment: @Nathanson@ can you show for me a different transformation?

Comment: The third one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) also works.